# indexing numpy multidimensional arrays

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I need to access this numpy array, sometimes with only the rows where the last column is 0, and sometimes the rows where the value of the last column is 1.

```
y = [0  0  0  0
     1  2  1  1 
     2 -6  0  1
     3  4  1  0]
```

I have to do this over and over, but would prefer to shy away from creating duplicate arrays or having to recalculate each time. Is there someway that I can identify the indices concerned and just call them? So that I can do this:

```
>>print y[LAST_COLUMN_IS_0] 
[0  0  0  0
3  4  1  0]

>>print y[LAST_COLUMN_IS_1] 
[1  2  1  1 
2 -6  0  1]
```

P.S. The number of columns in the array never changes, it's always going to have 4 columns.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use numpy's [boolean indexing](https://numpy.org/devdocs/user/quickstart.html#head-d55e594d46b4f347c20efe1b4c65c92779f06268) to identify which rows you want to select, and numpy's fancy indexing/slicing to select the whole row.

```
print y[y[:,-1] == 0, :]
print y[y[:,-1] == 1, :]
```

You can save `y[:,-1] == 0` and `... == 1` as usual, since they are just numpy arrays.

(The `y[:,-1]` selects the whole of the last column, and the `==` equality check happens element-wise, resulting in an array of booleans.)

Comment: +1, It works. But I'm having trouble understanding what `y[:,-1] == 0` is. It's a numpy array, but not a range? How can you then use it to index?

Comment: @Zach, http://www.scipy.org/Tentative_NumPy_Tutorial#head-d55e594d46b4f347c20efe1b4c65c92779f06268

Comment: Thanks. Quick additional question, how do I then select a column from the result. For example, to select the 1st column, this doesn't work: `y[y[:,-1] == 0, :][0]`